# How to use local json data to rtk-query endpoints?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am developing an application but backend apis are not ready, so I want to use dummy data by keeping related data in local json files.

In classic redux I used to make api call to some dummy endpoint and then in response i used set my local json data to update the redux store by dispatching action.

But with rtk-query i am struggling to save local data. I want to finish UI till backend apis get ready.

I can do this by old classic way but then later I have to remove classic way and integrate rtk-query and it will double work.

I need suggestions how can i develop my ui by using local json data using rtk-query.

I tried onQueryUpdate but it's look hacky and messy, so I need some standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mock-service-worker` to just fake the existence of your api until it actually exists.

Comment: mock server is the final, this is what i was thinking but thought it will be overkill. miragejs is good to mick server

Comment: `mock-service-worker` is not a full server, it just simulates that there is one by registering a service worker. It is what we use in the RTK Query tests ourselves, so it would be my prime recommendation.